# How to sort a collection based on a subcollection property

Tags: linq, sorting, c#-3.0, lambda, sql-order-by

I would like to sort a collection based on a subcollection property.

```
//the subcollection
public class Salary
{
   public int SalaryId {get;set;}
   public int SalaryYear {get;set;}
   public double SalaryValue {get;set;} //this is the field we want to sort the parent collection "Person"
}

//the main collection
public class Person
{
   public int PersonId {get;set;}
   public string PersonName {get;set;}
   public List<Salary> Salaries {get;set;}
}
```

Below just for testing purpose, I'm preparing my collection of person with Salaries inner collections each one:

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
//add two salaries for Junior
people.Add(new Person { PersonId = 1, PersonName = "Junior" });
people[0].Salaries.Add(new Salary { SalaryId=1, SalaryYear=2011, SalaryValue=80000 });
people[0].Salaries.Add(new Salary { SalaryId=2, SalaryYear=2010, SalaryValue=70000 });

//add two salaries for Johanna
people.Add(new Person { PersonId = 2, PersonName = "Johanna" });
people[0].Salaries.Add(new Salary { SalaryId=3, SalaryYear=2011, SalaryValue=40000 });
people[0].Salaries.Add(new Salary { SalaryId=4, SalaryYear=2010, SalaryValue=30000 });
```

Now we want to sort the people collection, but using their inner collection SalaryValue as parameter.

How can I sort List but using LINQ / Lambda expressions on Salaries inner collection?

So I would have:

```
PersonName: Johanna, SalaryValue=30000, SalaryYear=2010
PersonName: Johanna, SalaryValue=40000, SalaryYear=2011
PersonName: Junior, SalaryValue=70000, SalaryYear=2010
PersonName: Junior, SalaryValue=80000, SalaryYear=2011
```

Comment: the code lacks initialization of Salaries list field for a person (people[i])

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To me, that looks like:

```
var query = from person in people
            from salary in person.Salaries
            orderby salary.SalaryValue
            select new { person, salary };

foreach (var pair in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(pair);
}
```

Note that you're not really sorting a collection of *people* - you're sorting a collection of (person, salary), which is what the flattening effect of having two `from` clauses does.

(The above won't provide exactly the same output, but once you've got the person and their salary, you can get at the other values.)

Comment: This sorts on salary, independent of the outer collection. It's ambiguous if the poster cares if the list contains `Johanna:30000, Junior:70000, Johanna:75000, Junior:80000` or if he wants it to be `Johanna:30000, Johanna:75000, Junior:70000, Junior:80000`

Comment: @Marc: That's true... but as it's been accepted, I assume this is what was wanted.

Comment: Shouldn't `Writeline()` be a little more elaborated than just containing just the `pair`?

Comment: @GennadyVanin--Novosibirsk: Why? It's fine for diagnostic purposes at least.

Comment: You should have followed [advise by @Steven Sudit](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3471644/200449) to change to `select new { person.PersonName, salary.SalaryValue};`. Your `WriteLine(pair)` prints the lines repeating lines: `{person = NameSpaceName.Person, salary = NameSpaceName.Salary}` . So, the correct answer has zero upvotes and your "diagnostic" one +4

Comment: @GennadyVanin--Novosibirsk: Did you read the bottom part of my answer? (Ultimately, the question is about ordering - the output is unlikely to be really to the console anyway, so it's less relevant IMO. There's no need to put both aspects of the `salary` into the anonymous type - you could easily fetch them both when writing it out, if you really want.)

Comment: Nope. I am just running the code (without reading). I upvoted your answer to compensate my illiteracy

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Jon's logic is correct, but the sample code doesn't match the OP's. It should probably be more like this:

```
var query = from person in people
            from salary in person.Salaries
            orderby salary.SalaryValue
            select new { person.PersonName, salary.SalaryValue, salary.SalaryYear };

foreach (var tuple in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(tuple);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed my orderby clause. I haven't changed the projection - I figure once you've got the person and salary, you can print whatever bits you want and leave the rest.

Comment: @Jon: Thanks for putting up with my nitpicking. :-)